# Docker Error with Mysql, PHPmyadmin and Apache

Tags: php, mysql, docker, phpmyadmin

I have an php website that connects to an SQL website. I have created a docker compose an when ran, the Php site doesn't connect to mysql. 
My docker-config.yml:

```
    version: '3'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: AspireAdmin

  webserver:
    image: php:apache
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 24:80

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      PMA_HOST: db
      PMA_USER: root
      PMA_PASSWORD: AspireAdmin
    ports:
    - "8004:80"
    restart: always
    depends_on: 
    - db
```

Comment: What are the contents of `docker-compose logs webserver` after you try to access a page that needs to use the DB?  And make sure your first line `version "3"` has no spaces before it.

Comment: `webserver_1   | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.20.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message`

Comment: Alright, humor me with this...  Try image: mysql:5.6.

It may not work, but in 5.6, there were some defaults that made the MYSQL container much less finicky...  Try rebuilding your DB image and let me know if that works...  If it does, then if necessary, we can try some other things to make it work with the latest version.

Comment: Well... I found the issue, mysqli isn't installed. How would I install this in docker compose?

Comment: Try following the instructions on [this](https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/391) site.  You may have to create your own Dockerfile and extend the php:apache image with the build commands from that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not connect because your basic settings needs some adjustments.Your MYSQL needs his basic settings for startup correctly. Then you need to set network mode to bridge (this will make your containers connect to themselves by container_name). So that is what I'm doing in this docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    container_name: db
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpasswd
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=phpmyadmin
      - MYSQL_USER=user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=userpasswd
    networks:
      - db
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password

  webserver:
    image: php:apache
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 24:80

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:4.7
    restart: always
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - 9090:80
    networks:
      - external-net
      - db
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
    depends_on:
      - db

networks:
  external-net:
    external:
      name: external-net
  db:
    driver: bridge
```

I've created two networks, one for external access and other for db access, so, if your webserver needs to communicate with them, you just need to add it on the compose file. After deploying, you can access phpmyadmin with root:rootpasswd

Comment: Hi, I tried this however I still get the same error. `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in /var/www/html/index.php:9 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/index.php on line 9`

Comment: Hi @PremUdeshi, you need to install mysqli on your webserver part, you can do this by after using docker-compose up, you must need to attach into your webserver using docker ps(to get your container id) then use: docker exec -it <container_id> bash, and you install mysqli inside that container. That error comes from your webserver since the image php:apache does not have msqli installed by default. After doing that, you must commit your container to a new image and use it in your compose, got it?